# Google Maps Geolocation API accuracy

Tags: google-maps, geolocation

I am testing the Geolocation API and getting some strange results. 
I have (my) access points and know their Wifi MAC addresses. On server I need to get their position. I send 2 or more of these MAC addresses and in some cases get really good-precise location. In other cases I get location in completely different country.

I presume that in this case Google cannot determine location by Mac addresses (does not have enough data or whatever) and probably returning location based on my server IP (which is cloud hosted, different country etc).

Is there any way I can know that this calculation is based on MAC or Ip address so I can 'reject' IP results??

Solution I am currently using is that I accept result if accuracy is less than 500m (I assume it is correct result based on MACs) but would prefer if there is more reliable solution.

Thanks for any suggestions, answers etc.

Comment: You should be able to get more accurate results if you have GPS enabled, if it's not already.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on which browser you are using, the HTML5 Geolocation API approximates location based on a number of factors including your public IP address, cell tower IDs, GPS information, a list of Wifi access points, signal strengths and MAC IDs (Wifi and/or Bluetooth). It then passes that information to a Location Service usually via an HTTPS request which attempts to correlate your location from a variety of databases that include Wifi access point locations both public and private, as well as Cell Tower and IP address locations. An approximate location is then returned to your code via a JavaScript callback.

Your case looks like you are using a VPN. In case of VPN turned on, then the location will resolve to the VPN’s public IP address. For example, a user in Denver is logged into the company VPN which host is hosted at their headquarters office in a suburb of Dallas, Texas. The HTML5 Geolocation API will resolve the location to the headquarters public IP address in Dallas and not the user’s actual location. Quite a few corporate users have VPNs for security reasons.